# Get System IP and Port for DB2 ODBC DSN

Tags: db2, odbc, dsn

My program is written in VB.Net and connects to DB2 via ODBC.  For other ODBC connections we've been able to pull the host ip address via the registry.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\

DB2 doesn't seem to have any of this information so I'm wondering if there is a way to get the ip through the ODBC connection.

I also understand now there is a way to get this information via the DB2 Command Line Processor by running a combination of `list db directory` and then `list node directory`, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way via ODBC or perhaps some DB2 SQL Command...  Thanks for the help!

Comment: What DB2 version/platform?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the hostname for the DB2 server by using the following SQL statement:

```
select host_name, adapter_name from TABLE(ENV_GET_NETWORK_RESOURCES())
```

If you know what adapter_name, i.e., eth0, eth1, ... , ethN you want, you can add the predicate

```
WHERE adapter_name like '<adapter>%'
```

An example is:

```
db2 "select substr(host_name,1,20) as host, substr(adapter_name,1,10) as adapter from TABLE(ENV_GET_NETWORK_RESOURCES())"

HOST                 ADAPTER   
-------------------- ----------
dbms                 eth0      
dbms                 lo        

  2 record(s) selected.
```